# I do not understand this HeadFirst Java exercise

Tags: java

I'm reading Head First Java and an exercise is confusing me a little bit. The Original instructions of the exercise are irrelevant, however, the point is to be able to solve it with out just compiling the code and running it, which would just spit out the answer. I am quite confused and am trying to play the debugger and go step by step each line of code and see what is happening. I have added my comments to the code to make sure I am understanding it. Just need help understanding for example what the count is at a specific point and such.  Here is the original code, with one line added myself, which i've noted. Some of the lines I will note which I don't understand the best.

**Update: So I gave the best understanding on my code. Questions I have about certain lines are in the comments. If anyone can maybe do a step by step approach of what happens would make it a lot more understandable. Thank you all for your help in advance. I am new to StackOverFlow so hopefully this was the correct way of asking a question.

```
public class Mix4
{
    int counter = 0;    //This is setting the variable counter to 0.

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int count = 0;    //This is setting the variable count to 0.

        Mix4[] m4a = new Mix4[20];//This is initializing an array of 20 m4a objects to  null.

        int x = 0;        //This is setting the variable x to 0;

        while ( x < 9 )
        {
            m4a[x] = new Mix4(); //This actually creates the m4a object at array index 0.

            m4a[x].counter = m4a[x].counter + 1;
            //This line is very confusing. How can you use a dot operator on a variable?
            //I am saying variable because as stated above there is a int counter = 0;

            count = count + 1; //This increments the variable count. Why do this though?

            count = count + m4a[x].maybeNew(x);

            //The count variable again is being implemented but this time it calls the
            // maybeNew method and it is passing a 0 as as the argument? Why do this?

            x = x + 1; // x is being incremented. 

            System.out.println(count + " " + m4a[1].counter); 
            //What is this printing and when does this print?
        }

    public int maybeNew(int index)
    {
        if (index < 5)
        {
            Mix4 m4 = new Mix4(); //Creating a new object called m4.

            m4.counter = m4.counter + 1;
            //Same question about this from the code of line stated above using dot
            //operators on variables.

            return 1; //Where does 1 be returned to? I thought you can only have one
                      //return statement per method?
        }
        return 0; // I thought only 1 return statement? I have no idea what these return
                  // statements are doing
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: counter is a class variable. You can not access it from a static methoid like this anyway.

Comment: This is initializing an array of 20 m4a objects to  null. => not exactly. array itself has a capacity of 20 and but at the moment there is nothing in it.

Comment: @KorayTugay This is how the code was in the book. So you can not access **m4a[x].counter + 1;** ? I thought it was going to be **m4a[0].counter + 1;** where in the first array position of the object counter is set to 1?

Comment: You can not initialize an object to null, you can make a reference reffer to an object or make it null. Like MixM4 = null. The reference is pointing to null, no object initialized yet.

Comment: a dot on a variable accesses that object class variable if it is public so it is ok.

Comment: @KorayTugay so how I explained my reasoning about the dot operator and class variables is correct then? How it is storing the the value of the counter variable to that specific object in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 m4a[0].counter = m4a[x].counter + 1;
 //This line is very confusing. How can you use a dot operator on a variable?
 //I am saying variable because as stated above there is a int counter = 0;
```

`m4a` is an array of `Mix4` objects.  You can call object methods or properties(variables) using the `.` operator

```
 count = count + m4a[x].maybeNew(x);
 //The count variable again is being implemented but this time it calls the
 // maybeNew method and it is passing a 0 as as the argument? Why do this?
```

`maybeNew()` return an `int`.  You are trying to increase the count by whatever number `maybeNew(x)` returns.  `x` is the value of `m4a[0]`, if `x = 0`.

```
System.out.println(count + " " + m4a[1].counter); 
//What is this printing and when does this print?
```

This prints at end of your program.  It prints the `counter` value for the `Mix4` object at index `1` in the `m4a` array

```
return 1; //Where does 1 be returned to? I thought you can only have one
                  //return statement per method?
    }
    return 0; // I thought only 1 return statement? I have no idea what these return
              // statements are doing
```

First of all, a method may or may not return a value. In you method, you want it to return an `int`.  So when you call it here `count = count + m4a[x].maybeNew(x);`, it like saying, whatever number `maybeNew(x)` returns, add that to count.

Your first `return 1` is inside of a conditional statement.  If the condition is satisfied, `return 1`, else `return 0`

Comment: Are you saying you can access any class variables on objects using dot operators to increment counter for example for that specific object only? For the second answer you provided are you saying that count will hold whatever count is + whatever answer **m4a[0].maybeNew(0)** returns? Like what is the purpose of keeping count?

Comment: Ok I will. I have been reading the book in order I thought they would only put code that they have taught so far. But thank you for clearing up a lot of my questions! @peeskillet

Comment: Do you think that the book you are recommending is better than Head First Java. I heard really good ratings on Head First Java and I am about to start chapter 5. Once I get some of these exercises figured out.

Comment: I'm still using it.  I've been teaching myself JAVA and this is the best book I've come across.  It get really in depth and there are so many exercises to help you tone your understanding of concepts and there's a website you can go to for help and testing your knowledge.  Really great book.  Get the latest 9th edition the comprehensive version if you do decide to pick it up.  You'll also pick up on a lot of good coding practice.

Answer (score 0):

**Where does 1 be returned to? I thought you can only have one 
return statement per method?**

You may have have one `return` statement for one branch in your function, its not restricting to have one one `return` statement per function, its should be only one `return` statement for  one logic path. Like :

```
public int DoStuff(Foo foo) {
   if (foo == null) return 0;
   ...
   return 1; // any thing 
 }
```

---

**m4a[0].counter = m4a[x].counter + 1;

//This line is very confusing. How can you use a dot operator on a variable?
 //I am saying variable because as stated above there is a int counter = 0;**

m4a `is an array of`Mix4`Class objects. You can call object methods or properties using` the `.` operator.
From [Using Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html)

> Code that is outside the object's class must use an object reference or expression, followed by the dot (.) operator, followed by a simple field name, as in:

```
objectReference.fieldName
```

---

**System.out.println(count + " " + m4a[1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html).counter);    
//What is this printing and when does this print?**

From  [System.out.println()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.Object%29)

> Prints an Object and then terminate the line. This method calls at first String.valueOf(x) to get the printed object's string value, then behaves as though it invokes print(String) and then println().

It will print the `count` value, and `counter` value for the Mix4 object at index 1 in the m4a array.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. For some reason the Head First Book stated that only one return statement per method so I got a little confused with that. So like in my code how does the logic work for that? Like does it always return 1 as long as index is less than 5? Does it always return 0 just because the method needs to return something and return 0 is just the default way to say you already returned something and this is just to close the method out?

Comment: yes you are right it always return 1 as long as index is less than 5.

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = 0;        //This is setting the variable x to 0;
```

You got this part right
Now inside while loop in the 1st iteration x = 0;

```
Mix4[] m4a = new Mix4[20];
```

This again as you correctly guesses is just defining of an array. Simply putting it is a group of 20 reference of type Mix which woould point to the actuall Object of type Mix. Now you have to assign these objects to the references which is what we are doing in the while loop.

```
m4a[x] = new Mix4();
```

Here in 1st iretartion we are `doing m4a[0] = new Mix4();` so the element at index 0 is initialized.

m4a[0].counter = m4a[x].counter 
 Here we are simply accessing the counter of the actual object and assigning value to it.

How can you use a dot operator on a variable?
 First if all m4a[0] has been initialized. Next thing you need to know is acess modifieer. If you look at the statement

```
  int counter = 0;
```

No access modifer is specified which means it has default access modifier. Now for default access modifier visibilty of a variable is in the same class and same package(No need of getter/setter methods).

Also note that counter is an instance variable(not local variable) and instance variables are assigned default values(for int it is 0, for String it is null and so on...)

Try to debug the code step by step with this basic understanding.

Comment: Thank you for help! I am coding everything I have in VIM. I am not trying to use an IDE yet and so I can't do step by step.

Comment: @user an IDE will help so much in your learning.  Especially the dropdown lists of methods in the auotcomplete utility, if will teach you alot about the methods and their functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Your code as you have shown above will not compile for two reasons:

1. You have the `System.out.println`inside the while loop; this will result in a NullPointerException as when the compiler gets to `m4a[1].counter` the m4a[1] object has not been created. Only m4a[0] has been created. Alternatively you can leave this line where it is but change it to `m4a[0].counter`
2. You have the `maybeNew(int index)` method declaration inside `main`; this is mostly likely just a mistake with your curly brackets but just so you know you can't declare a method inside another method; `main` is a method and so you must declare `maybeNew`outside it but call it from within `main`

   ```
    public class Mix4 {
    int counter = 0;
    public static void main (String[] args) {
    int count = 0;
    Mix4[] m4a = new Mix4[20];
    int x = 0;

    while (x < 9) {
       m4a[x] = new Mix4();
       m4a[x].counter = m4a[x].counter + 1;
       count = count + 1;
       count = count + m4a[x].maybeNew(x);
       x = x + 1;
      // System.out.println(count + " " + m4a[0].counter);
   }
    System.out.println(count + " " + m4a[1].counter);
   }
       public int maybeNew(int index)
   {
    if (index < 5)
   {
       Mix4 m4 = new Mix4();
       m4.counter = m4.counter + 1;
       return 1;
   }
    return 0;
   }
   }
   ```